# Capturing request and response like fiddler does in C#

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-activity

How can I capture my request and response for my android application and write those in text file like fiddler does to capture all the request and response?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use Fiddlr on a PC and proxy the device's http request through it. This can be a complex topic depending on your needs and scenario .  For more info, look up "reverse proxy with Fiddlr".

In general, the steps involved are :

In Fiddlr, enable remote connections. By default, this will be done on port 8888. You may have to allow access through your PC firewall, too.

On the device, go to your WiFi connection, modify it and change the proxy settings, providing your PC IP address or FQDN and port.

Verify operations by browsing to a web site from the device and examining Fiddlr capture.

For https traffic, you will also need to enable https decryption in Fiddlr and install the Fiddlr cert to the device.

Comment: thanks but i need fiddler like api for my android app and to catch those response and request in app only.

Comment: This is something you want to do with the app in production?

Comment: yes i want this for app in production and i want the catched response and request for data analysis... so i cannot use third party to catch these...

Comment: If that's the case, I would just wrap up whatever HttpClient I was using using with my own client and then capture the raw response and request streams.  For example, to facilitate unit testing, I will always have a service layer that abstracts http activity from the app.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com).

Basically all you have to do is start Charles on your PC and configure http://:8888 as the proxy on your Android devices.

You can also use it with browsers and Android emulators. See [their Android documentation](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/browser-and-system-configuration/) for examples.